# Vue loop with conditional like PHP

Tags: php, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I am very new to vue, and still stuck with some conditional that I usually solved with PHP. I am trying to loop an element with a conditional inside it. Here is the element i want to look like:

```
<ul>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>C</li>
    <li>D</li>
</ul>
```

Here is my code :

```
<template v-for="(grade , counter) in grades">
    <template v-if="counter % 2 === 0">
        <ul>
    </template>

    <li>{{ grade }}</li>

    <template v-if="counter % 2 == 1">
        </ul>
    </template>
</template>

<script>
new Vue({
    el : "#app",
    data : {
        grades : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    },
});
</script>
```

And the result is :

```
<ul>
</ul>
<li>A</li>
<li>B</li>
<ul>
</ul>
<li>C</li>
<li>D</li>
```

Sorry the above code is just an example, but more or less it is the problem i am dealing with. Can someone help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: Can you post your array/object pls?

Comment: @Badgy thank you, i just updated it

Comment: Change it from `<template v-if="...">` to `<div v-if="...">`

Comment: Welcome. Always print the first `<ul>` and last `</ul>` and on condition print `</ul><ul>`

Comment: @JustCarty i just tried your suggestion and it did work but somehow some result is lost, the html result : <ul><li>A</li></ul><ul><li>C</li></ul>...it only display A and C ?

Comment: @kerbholz can you give me some example ?

Comment: Just add a wrapping div should solve it.

Comment: In fact, I am being stupid, move the `v-if` directive onto the `<ul>` and remove the wrapping parent of the `<ul>` elements

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the `render` function in this case to reduce the complexity in the template as below

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    grades: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
  },
  render (createElement) {
    const elements = [];
    const step = 2;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.grades.length; i += step) {
      elements.push(
        createElement(
          'ul',
          {},
          this.grades.slice(i, i + step).map(grade => createElement('li', {}, grade)))
      )
    }

    return createElement('div', {}, elements);
  }
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cf37vta9/

Reference: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html